# Filter stdin of process executed with socat client

Tags: linux, macos, bash, zsh, socat

My question is: is there a way to pre-process the stdin of a command executed via socat client.

Context:
I am launching a reverse shell with `socat` using this command:

```
$> socat -T30 "openssl-connect:api.hoposhell.com:10000,verify=0,keepalive" "exec:$SHELL,pty,stderr,setsid"
```

In order to keep the connection alive, my server sends the ACK ASCII character (0x06) every 10 seconds.
However, this has side effects in some applications and some `^F` characters appears.

In bash or zsh it is possible to use pipes with sed like below:

```
$> echo "rick roll" | sed 's/r//g'
ick oll
```

Is there a way to do something similar with socat? (e.g. use cat between the socket read and the executed command)

Note:

- this is a follow up to this question
  [Keep alive SSL client connection with socat](https://superuser.com/questions/1687891/keep-alive-ssl-client-connection-with-socat)
- I would be happy with other ASCII character (other than 0x06) if that allows to circumvent the issue
- I am using bash and zsh under linux and macos (Big Sur)

*Edit: simple equivalent example*

Let us say I listen to the reverse shell with (machine 1)

```
1> socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:4242 STDOUT
```

and connect a reverse shell with (machine 2)

```
2> socat TCP4:localhost:4242 SYSTEM:/bin/bash,pty,setsid,stderr
```

I can now use a shell from computer 1 (executed on computer 2)
Now I want that everytime I send character 0x06 from 1 to 2, is is ignored.

Now, if I replace by:

```
2>  socat TCP4:localhost:4243 SYSTEM:"/usr/bin/sed -u 's/a/b/g' | bash -i",pty,setsid,stderr
```

Now I should get a reverse shell when all the "a" become "b" as below (on machine 1). But I get two issues:

- when I type "a", the "a" is still shown (twice) as below (I pressed "la" + ENTER)

```
bash-3.2$ la
la
lb
bash: lb: command not found
bash-3.2$
```

- when my server sends some "a" characters they still appear as is

```
bash-3.2$ aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
bash: bbbbbbbbbb: command not found
bash-3.2$
```

My objective is to get respectively:

```
bash-3.2$ lb
bash: lb: command not found
bash-3.2$ bbbbbbbbbb
bash: bbbbbbbbbb: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The post
[Sed with port forwarding in socat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560821/sed-with-port-forwarding-in-socat)
recommends using a command similar to:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8002,fork SYSTEM:/path/to/replace.sh
```

The file `replace.sh` should have the execution permission.

An example for changing all `a` to `b`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -u 's/a/b/g'
```

For sed, it is important to use `-u` (unbuffered).

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question